# What should I change input_shape to?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

I'm going to learn data with 3Dtensor input.

My model is

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

class AnomalyDetector(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,input_shape=(36,501), activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation= "relu")
        ])
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,input_shape=(36,501), activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(140, activation= "sigmoid")
        ])
    
    def call(self,x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded
model = AnomalyDetector()
```

The shape of the 3dtensor is

(1500, 36, 501)

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size = 512, validation_data=(vali_X, vali_y), shuffle=True)
```

and Error is...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [155], in <cell line: 12>()
      9         print(e)
     11 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 12 model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size = 512, validation_data=(vali_X, vali_y), shuffle=True)

.
.
.
   

     ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_58" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 501), found shape=(None, 36, 8)
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer "anomaly_detector_30" (type AnomalyDetector):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 36, 501), dtype=float32)
```

I already change encoder's Dense 8 to 501. but another error occurred.

How should I change this?

Answer (score 1):

1. `Dense` doesn't take 3d input it takes 1d input for example :
   `input_shape = ( ,40)`  here 40 is the number of columns and i left a space because at start your model dosen't knows the length of data that's why in `model.summary()`
   `input_shape = (None,40)`  comes.
2. Is your input an image ?? if yes than `Dense` dosen't work on image use `Conv2D` or `Conv3D` as per your input data.

If i am wrong and Dense layer takes 3d input, correct me and please provide the link where you read about it.Thanks

Comment: No, it can take N dimensional inputs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense#input-shape

Comment: It is preprocessed sound-wav file. thank you for your kindness. 3D input is working. However, input and output do not match

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the input of your decoder. The decoder sets to get tensors of size (36,501) but it gets the output of the encoder that is a tensor of size (36,8) if you change your decoder input your code work :

```
class AnomalyDetector(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,input_shape=(36,501), activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation= "relu")
        ])
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,input_shape=(36,8), activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(140, activation= "sigmoid")
        ])
    
    def call(self,x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded
```

But be careful your encoder just embeds the second size of (Y) your image. I think you should flatten the image for your first layer which means something like this :

```
class AnomalyDetector(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation= "relu")
        ])
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation= "relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(140, activation= "sigmoid")
        ])
    
    def call(self,x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. But I still can't solve it.